# Use Python to find groups of consecutive numbers in excel

Tags: python

SO i embarked on learning python a couple of weeks ago through codecademy and it has been a slow process for me. But unfortunately I'm at a point right now that i need a script to do a specific function for me right now.

I have an excel doc that is a list of ID numbers, example - 
72100234
72100235
72100239

There are roughly 50,000 id numbers. I need a script that will do a couple of things for me.
 - first is to show me how the job is done so i can learn from it
 - second is its purpose, I need it to go through and find the consecutive numbers and group them together in either a separate file or another tab

Example -

72100234
72100235
72100236

72100239
72100240

I have to find these blocks of numbers so they can be assigned to a specific agency and going through the list manually... yeah, been there, done that, dont want to do it again.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this is not a platform where we  create code from scratch to solve your problems, can you share any code you've already written and point out where you're having issues?

If your code is working but you think it is inefficient, I would suggest looking at the Code Review stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

try to divide your problem into different steps.

The first step could be to get familiar with a library to access your excel file. The one i tend to use is "openpyxl". To find out how to get data from an excel file you can use this link: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html.
I am new here aswell and i found out that you should first make an affort to try yourself and afterwards people will be very helpful.

After you found out how to get the data from excel to python you could provide some of it. That would make it easier to understand your problem. I hope i could help you a bit.